# Plantar Fasciitis help

Tags: running, cardio, foot-pain

A little over a year ago I was on the first day of the second month of insanity and felt something "snap" in my left foot. It hurt like hell for a week and has remained an intermittent pain ever since.

I despise it because I can't seem to do any training and have put on a lot of weight. To be frank, I hate the way I look and, since I've also been balding for the last few years, my social anxiety has gone up tremendously and my self esteem has dropped down SO much. I hate photos of me. I hate videos of me. I can't even talk to women anymore. I mean it's just really, really pathetic and I know it.

Anyway, I'm trying again. I bought new weights, new running shoes, compression socks(which have helped tremendously), I've changed my diet and enrolled in nutrisystem. I've been getting at least fourty five minutes of cardio and half an hour of weights in every day.

My problem is that, though the compression socks help a great deal, sometimes when I wake up my foot hurts really bad and it takes a few hours for it to feel normal enough to even consider jogging. This is an issue because I like jogging in the early morning and evening honestly because there's virtually a zero percent chance of anyone seeing me on the trails.

Are there any exercises to help with the pain or any recommendations that may assist me to alleviate the tension in my foot in the morning? I'm sorry for the length of the question, thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had Plantar Fasciitis and it certainly is hard to resolve. I have also been bald for more than 30 years and I am embrace the fact that I don't have to do my hair in the morning. EVER! (Be bald and be proud ;)

There are a number of exercises that you can do to help. Perhaps there are to many to list here but these have helped me.

1) Towel scrunches - In your bare feet ball a towel under your feet. 
2) Make sure you stretch your feet in the morning before you get out of bed. I use a large band or even a sock to pull your toes towards you.
3) Calf raises and stretches

These three are listed here http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/plantar-fasciitis/multimedia/foot-stretches-to-prevent-plantar-fasciitis/img-20008230

In addition I have worn a boot at night. This helps to keep your foot in a 90 degree position and will help heal your plantar.

I wear (wore) Danskos. (https://www.dansko.com/) The solid bottom help support my foot while I walked during the day.

I wear very thick running shoes (I wear and LOVE Hoka's) The fact that it lets your foot bend less keeps you arch from collapsing while you are running.
http://www.hokaoneone.com/  I recommend the Bondi4 for a great shoe to start.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried the suggested exercises literally today and it honestly worked perfectly. It hurt for the first few minutes but then I felt it loosen a bit and within half an hour I was able to slip out of the house to the trail. Thanks!